# Covering dimension of the union

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

Let $\{{A_n}\}$ be the closed subsets of $X$, such that ${A_n} \subset \operatorname{Int}{A_{n + 1}}$ and $ \cup {A_n} = X$, if $A_1$ and all $\operatorname{cl}(A_n-A_{n-1})$ have the covering dimension at most $m$, does $X$ have the covering dimension at most $m$?

Comment: "\rm{Int}" A doesn't look the same as "\operatorname{Int} A"; the latter provides proper spacing before and after "Int": $\operatorname{Int} A$.  But curly braces around the first part wrecks that: {\operatorname{Int}} A: ${\operatorname{Int}} A$.  When you figure out why that's how it _ought_ to work, you'll understand something about typesetting.  (This distinction between the effects of \rm and of \operatorname doesn't work on Wikipedia, but I think that may change when they adopt mathJax in a few months.

Comment: Your example should be `{\rm Int} A` rather than `\rm{Int} A`, since `\rm` doesn't take a parameter — it is simply a switch that changes the current font.